# How to show actual application size in control panel?

Tags: inno-setup

How to show application actual size in control panel Programs and Features ?

**I know i should use `#define Myappsize` but don't know proper way.**

Anybody please help.

THANKS!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To modify the setup size that can be seen in the *Add/Remove Programs* control panel applet you can change the value of the [`UninstallDisplaySize`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_uninstalldisplaysize) directive. To set it to a certain (single) file size at the compilation time you can use the preprocessor's [`FileSize`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=filesize) function. For example:

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program
UninstallDisplaySize={#FileSize('C:\Deployment\MyApp.exe')}
```

Comment: Should i write file size in MB or Kb?

Comment: That value is in bytes, so as the size returned by the `FileSize` function (it's said in the help topics I've linked). I don't know where would you write what. I thought you're asking how to set that value to the size of a certain file, but now I'm confused...