# Inno Setup - About #define

Tags: size, inno-setup

In my script, there is a definition as (#define AppSize) -ignore brackets-.

This definition describes size of application which is installed.

But, my setup includes three applications and installations of these apps are optional.

I mean, if the user checks App A checkbox; App A will be installed. If the user checks App B...

So, how to set AppSize according to selected applications?

Comment: For what is that `AppSize` variable used in your script ?

Comment: I always use external compression and I write size manually to AppSize. For example, my app size is 10 MB. I write AppSize as #define AppSize "10". So, my checkboxes aren't in Components section.

Answer (score 0):

You can look into my asked question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30830577/how-to-show-actual-application-size-in-control-panel).
For check box use component part and select size from there.